# MySql Compound Unique Index of type Varchar

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unique, unique-index

Here is my situation:

```
• I have a table of users <br><br>
• I have a table of movies <br><br>
• I have a table of user_movies that associates users to movies that stores a frequently changing "score" column on each record.<br><br>
• I need to be able to bulk update the user_movies table for speed and to do so I believe I need a unique index to be able to pull off bulk updates like this.<br><br>
• Considering each user_movie combination is unique, would it be possible to do
```

Do something like `(User_id--->) uid_mid (<----movie_id)` as a unique identifier? If so how would one go about transitioning an existing table into this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but you understand you can create an index on two columns, right? "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myindex ON user_movies(user_id, movie_id)" (If you are always specifying both columns on all your queries against that table, the order of the columns won't matter).

Comment: How can I do a bulk update using 2 columns that together make a unique index, but do not separately?

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding something here. How are you doing the bulk update?

Comment: I use  $this->db->update_batch('extra_config', $updateData,'id');
} in Codeigniter , it requires a single unique id to do this kind of bulk update.

Comment: I found this which unpacks what CodeIgniter is doing more specifically: 

'
// Produces: 
// UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
// ELSE `name` END,
// `date` = CASE 
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
// ELSE `date` END
// WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')'

Comment: I am not familiar with codeigniter so I won't try to answer specific to that, but hopefully this additional information is useful for someone who can help you. (The 2 column unique id would help performance if you manually created a similar update statement to what codeignighter is doing.) I'm going to post a more general answer, although I don't really like it and hope you find a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to think there's a way to use a two-column index for your problem, however...

I guess to answer the original question and assume you really want to combine the columns into one, I would suggest considering something like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE user_movies ADD COLUMN new_id VARCHAR(250);

UPDATE user_moves SET new_id=CONCAT(CAST(user_id as CHAR(125)), LPAD(CAST(move_id as CHAR(125)),125,'0'));

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX myindex ON user_movies(new_id);
```

The numbers 250 and 125 are arbitrary of course, but you'd want them big enough to fit your actual ids. I am padding the second id to make sure they are truly unique (since we don't want user_id=55/movie_id=66 to get the same id as user_id=5/movie_id=566).